# Pyright Python linter doesn't recognize imports in Neovim

Tags: python, neovim, linter

I'm trying to learn how to use Python imports properly, but my linter in Neovim (Pyright) produces the following error message despite being able to run the code:

```
Import "subdir1.test1" could not be resolved [Pyright: reportMissingImports]
```

I have indicated via a comment below where this linting error occurs. My Python 3 test project has the following directory structure:

```
__init__.py
main.py
subdir1
  __init__.py
  test1.py
  test2.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty, and the other files have the following content:

**main.py**

```py
from subdir1.test2 import print_message_2
print_message_2()
```

**test1.py**

```py
def print_message():
    print(__name__)
```

**test2.py**

```py
from subdir1.test1 import print_message # the error comes from this line

def print_message_2():
    print_message()
```

How do I use Python imports the right way, so that the linter doesn't complain?
Is it even possible to open the `test2.py` file and not get linting errors?

Comment: How did you install your _pyright_? Please, share your lsp config. It may be a state where python which launches _pytright_ and the one that actually launchers your files are different.

Comment: Where do I find my lsp config? I ghink that pyright was just installed as a dependency with conqueror of completion, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, I see, I've never used coq, sorry, won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file called `pyrightconfig.json` in the root directory of your project and add the following lines to it:

```json
{
    "executionEnvironments": [
        {"root": "src"}
    ]
}
```

Configuring Pyright in general is explained in the [`configuration.md`](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

Therein, it explains that you need to pass a list of execution environments via the JSON-formatted text configuration. By default, this file is called `pyrightconfig.json` and is located within the root directory of your project

The passed-in execution environments are then searched from start to finish by comparing the path of a source file with the root path specified in the execution environment. This allows Pyright to resolve import statements.

Further information on the execution environment can be found in the [Execution Environment Options](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#execution-environment-options) section. An example JSON configuration file is given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#sample-config-file)---it may be worth having a look at it (and the rest of the `configuration.md` file) to find any other settings you might want to configure.